# React Native Android: Linking.addEventListener() not working

Tags: android, react-native

Does `Linking.addEventListener()` work in android? if no, Can you suggest something that works in android?

Thanks...

Comment: Yes addEventListener should work if you have set correct Intent filters in AndroidManifest. Which aspect is not working for you?

Comment: My intent filters are ok but when I listen to linking in componentDidMount I see no result.

Comment: I can't even find the corresponding event emitting code on the native (java) side. Is it implemented at all?